# How can I Remove Item from Queue or List with Unknown Type?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following with a private nested struct

```
public class A {
  
  private Queue<B> blah = new Queue<B>();

  private struct B { some fields... }

}
```

and I need to modify `blah` at runtime. I can't touch that code; it belongs in another dll.

So far I tried

```
A test = new A();

FieldInfo f = typeof(A).GetField("blah",BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

object k = f.GetValue(test);

List<object> list = ((ICollection)k).Cast<object>().ToList();

list.RemoveAt(0);

var nextQ = Activator.CreateInstance(f.GetUnderlyingType());

//How do I copy the modified list into nextQ??

f.SetValue(test, nextQ);
```

The problem is, nextQ is of type `object`. So how can I copy the modified list into it? Activator has an overload for calling Queue's constructor, but I can't use that since I can't cast `list` to `IEnumerable<B>`, and I just get an error about the constructor is not found.

Comment: Not quite clear what you want. Do you want to completely exchange the blah instance with a different one or do you want to just enqueue another B (or multiple B)?

Comment: Do you just want to dequeue the first item?

Comment: I just need to dequeue some of the original queue based on a condition. How do I call dequeue when `k` is only type object?

Comment: have you tried this: `fieldInfo field = type.GetField("blah", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        List<B> privateList = (List<B>)field.GetValue(test);
        privateList.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: @SebastianSiemens That doesn't work because B is private; I'm unable to use it as a type from my code. I just know it exists in the dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to dequeue an item, just call `Dequeue()` method on the queue.

assuming you have the following in the other assembly:

```
internal class B
{
    public string? Prop { get; set;}
}

public class A
{
    private Queue<B> blah;

    public A()
    {
        blah = new Queue<B>();
        blah.Enqueue(new B { Prop = "1" });
        blah.Enqueue(new B { Prop = "2" });
        blah.Enqueue(new B { Prop = "3" });
    }
}
```

You can write the following code to dequeue one item:

```
var a = new A();
var queueField = typeof(A).GetField("blah", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var queueValue = queueField.GetValue(a);
var queueType = queueValue.GetType();
var dequeueMethod = queueType.GetMethod("Dequeue");
var countProperty = queueType.GetProperty("Count");
Console.WriteLine(countProperty.GetValue(queueValue).ToString());
object dequeuedObject = dequeueMethod.Invoke(queueValue, null);
Console.WriteLine(countProperty.GetValue(queueValue).ToString());
```